# Where can I find a font with numbers, letters and symbols to use in a design of a calculator?

Tags: fonts

I am looking for a font to use in a calculator. It needs to have alphabetic characters (a-z), and hopefully mathematics symbols like:

`+` `−` `x` `÷` `(` `)`

It's for using it in a calculator app design. Any recommendations?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you mean the display (e.g. a 7-segment display as per John's answer) or the buttons? I think the vagueness is why people have voted to close.

Comment: I need to font for the display (result) and mathematic formula [e.g. (3 + 4) ÷ 2 = ], not for the buttons on the keypad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are literally trying to make it look like a calculator, there are many fonts that emulate digital displays.

Since you are looking for all alphanumeric characters, a [7-segment display](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display_character_representations#Display_pattern_tables) probably wouldn't be useful because there are too many shared glyphs.

Alternatively, you could use a [Fourteen Segment Display](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourteen-segment_display) font:

[image: 14 Seg Characters]

[Segment14](http://openfontlibrary.org/font/segment14) seems to meet your requirements, if that's the style you're looking for.

[image]

Another direction would be to mimic the display of a more modern calculator, such as a TI-83:

[image: TI-83 Font]

Search for '5x7 pixel font' to find similar fonts to this, [Pixxel v2.2](http://fontstruct.com/fontstructions/show/468995) looks very similar